# How to create a stored procedure that can accept parameters, and delete the corresponding record?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a couple of tables that includes information about customers. I am trying to create a stored procedure accepts three parameters and deletes the record that matches those parameters.

Here's what I have so far

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DELETE_CUSTOMER(
                                            customer_id_arg    IN DECIMAL,
                                            first_name_arg     IN VARCHAR,
                                            last_name_arg      IN VARCHAR
                                           ) IS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM CUSTOMER
          WHERE customer_id IN (SELECT customer_last
                                  FROM Customer
                                 WHERE customer_id = customer_id_arg);
END;
```

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What seems to be the problem ?

Comment: which dbms? and what is the problem? are you having an error or what?

Comment: I removed all the specific DBMS tags. Feel free to add back the one that you are actually using.

Comment: Oracle. Adding more characters to pass the 15 character min

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stored procedure for deleting records in Oracle DBMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819578/stored-procedure-for-deleting-records-in-oracle-dbms)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this line:

```
DELETE FROM CUSTOMER customer_id IN (SELECT customer_last ...
```

You checking for an ID in a result set of Last Names.  These will never match.  You can simplify this by just doing the following:

```
Delete From CUSTOMER Where customer_id = customer_id_arg
```

This is assuming that Customer_ID is Unique.  If it is not unique, then you may have to include the name as well:

```
Delete From CUSTOMER 
Where customer_id = customer_id_arg
    and customer_last = last_name_arg
    and customer_first = first_name_arg
```